# Derivative of a vector to a matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

I am confused by matrix calculus for hours, since I found different versions of relative computations online.

Suppose there is a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{L\times K}$, and a column vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^{K\times 1}$, now I want to take the derivative: $\frac{\partial Ax}{\partial A}$.

The first version of formula I found online suggested to simply take derivatives of the column vector w.r.t. matrix element-wisely, so for each scalar in that vector, I need to find the derivative of that scalar w.r.t to the matrix. Then I checked what did it say about the derivate of a scalar w.r.t. a matrix. It said that I need to take derivatives of that scalar w.r.t. each element of the matrix, element-wisely, so the result is a matrix with the same scale.

However, if the above statement was true, then for each of $L$ elements in $Ax$, I would get a matrix with scale $L\times K$. As a consequence, for $\frac{\partial Ax}{\partial A}$ I would get a matrix with scale $L^{2} \times K$. I think it is totally wrong because it deviates from the expected answer.

Then I found most of the answers online suggested that the result is actually $x^{T}\otimes \mathbb{I}$, and it raised furthermore questions to me.

Firstly, how may I get the correct result? How to look its derivation in an intuitive and understandable way?

Secondly, I also found the article "matrix calculus" on Wikipedia, it generalized almost every situation in a very long table, which is hard to remember and not comprehensive at all. Is there a universal rule or general solution to such problems?

Comment: What kind of object do you expect/want the derivative of a vector function of a matrix argument to be? Presumably some kind of tensor with three indices?

Comment: Yeah, I think a tensor with three indices can be a reasonable result, but I don't know what specific rules to follow. Does the final answer actually depend on my expectation? Because someone just told me that there are conventions on it (which means the answer may not be unique?).

Comment: I mean, all the answers will be in some way equivalent, whether you're putting indices up top or down below or you're thinking about a vector of matrices or a matrix of vectors or whatever - it's the same collection of numbers, just visualized/interpreted/used differently for different conventions/contexts. If you want to think of the answer as a matrix of vectors, then the $ij$ entry should be a vector which is the derivative of $Ax$ with respect to $a_{ij}$, which will be $x_j$ times the basis vector $e_i$.

Comment: I see, I just wrote down the result in a pure matrix form, but I didn't think in that way... I may figure this out now, thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\d{\delta}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\p{\partial}\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$The most straightforward approach is to write the equation using the [Einstein summation convention](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EinsteinSummation.html), then calculate the gradient directly as
$$\eqalign{
y_{i} &= A_{ij}\,x_{j} \\
\grad{y_{i}}{A_{pq}}
 &= \bigg(\grad{A_{ij}}{A_{pq}}\bigg)\,x_{j} \\
 &= (\d_{ip}\d_{jq})\,x_{j} \\
 &= \d_{ip}\,x_{q} \\
}$$
where $\d_{ij}$ is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) symbol.

As you can see, the result contains 3 free indices, and is therefore a third-order tensor.

Another approach is to consider a set of *vector-valued* gradients
(one for each component of $A$)
$$\eqalign{
y &= Ax \\
\grad{y}{A_{pq}} &= \bigg(\grad{A}{A_{pq}}\bigg)\,x
 = E_{pq}\,x 
 = e_p\,e_q^Tx 
 = e_p\,x_q 
\\
}$$
where $E_{pq}=e_pe_q^T\,$ is a matrix whose components are all zero except for the $(p,q)^{th}$ component which is equal to one.  Similarly, $e_p$ is a vector whose components are all zero except for the $(p)^{th}$ component which is equal to one.

A related approach is to consider a set of *matrix-valued* gradients
(one for each component of $y$)
$$\eqalign{
y_{i} &= A_{ij}\,x_{j} \\
\grad{y_i}{A}
 &= \bigg(\grad{A_{ij}}{A}\bigg)\,x_{j}  
 &= E_{ij}\,x_{j} 
 &= e_{i}e_{j}^Tx_{j} 
 &= e_{i}x^T \\
}$$

All of these results are awkward to work with and to calculate.  I suspect that you **think** you need this particular third-order tensor because you are attempting to apply the *Chain Rule* as part of a bigger problem.

If that is the case, then you should be aware that there are methods for solving such problems which **do not** require these higher-order tensors.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right! I was trying to apply the chain rule on a series of matrix multiplications, which hence raised me this question. Your answer and approaches are really helpful! Appreciate it!